# Targetting dynamically added content using jQuery Mobile

Tags: ajax, jquery, jquery-mobile

This is my main page:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    // Hide e2 and e3
    $(document).on('pagechange', function(){
        $("#e2").hide();
        $("#e3").hide();
    }); 

// Ajax call to insert e1-e3
$(document).on('pageshow', function(){
    $("#course").bind("change", function() {
        $.ajax({
             type: "GET", 
             url: "includes/db/ajax.php",
             data: "course="+$("#course").val(),
             success: function(html) {
                $("#insert-es").html(html);
                $("#page").trigger('create');
            }
        });     
    });
}); 
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="insert-quests">
         <div id="insert-es"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Ajax.php will generate a list of divs based on a database table, for example...

```
<div id="e1">...</div>
<div id="e2">...</div>
<div id="e3">...</div>
```

Prior to adding these divs through jQuery and AJAX, I was able to hide 2 and 3 using this script below. (I need to do this because 2 and 3 are only supposed to be shown when the user selects a certain response in 1.)

```
$(document).on('pageinit', function(){
    $("#2").hide();
    $("#3").hide();
});
```

So I have two questions:

I tried pagechange and some other events but no result. How can I use jQuery mobile on content after I have brought it in using AJAX?

The amount of divs is related to the amount of entries in a table of the database. How can I get the amount of entries, so that I can just use a loop there? For example...

```
for ( var i = 0; i < amount_of_entries ; i++ ) {
    $("#e" + i).hide();
}
```

Comment: hide divs during ajax call? or when?

Comment: after the ajax call is a success

Comment: first of all... you better change your ids from number to string so that you won't fall into more problems in future

Comment: Why not `display:none`? Or did I misunderstand your question? :-)

Comment: still your question isn't clear. Ajax is called when? and on which page? hide contents in same page or different one?

Comment: @bipen The numbers are just here to make the example clearer, but thanks. :-)

Comment: @Omar Does adding the main page help to make the question clear?

Comment: @hungerpain Wouldn't I still need to target them with jQuery to remove the display:none when I want to reveal the divs again?

Comment: Yeah.you just need to call `show()` when the user has chosen the first option, @MacBryce

Comment: after `$("#page").trigger('create');` add `$('#2, #3').hide();`. remove `pagechange` event.

Comment: Its all abt calling the `hide` method when the `ediv`s are available. Call it after you add the `html` into that `div`.

Comment: But a better cleaner option would be to use CSS for this, you could set display:none to #e2 and #e3 before hand and show them when needed. @MacBryce

Comment: @omar Thank you. That does hide them. The only problem is that I still need to be able to bring them back after the AJAX call, for example when a button inside of div 'e1' is clicked.

Comment: same thing after hiding them `$(document).on('click', '#2,#3', function () { code });`

Comment: @hungerpain You mean that I should target a class (that sets display:none) in CSS then?

Comment: @omar Of course. Why didn't I see that right away. Thanks!

Comment: Does anyone have a solution for the second part of the question as well? (i.e. how can you edit the #e1 to #eN in jQuery if you need to access the database to figure out N?)

Comment: welcome! second part isn't clear as well :)

Comment: @omar I've edited it. Is this clearer?

Comment: If you add a class to your divs instead of hiding them based on their ID, you should just be able to hide all the divs at once like $('.class-name').hide();

Comment: You want to know number of entries retrieved by ajax call? `success: function(html) { var entries = html.lenght`.

Comment: @JacobVanScoy Great idea, but unfortunately, I need to target them one by one.

Comment: You should post your answer into the answer @hungerpain, comments can be deleted at any time (and you don't actually get reputation for them).

Comment: @omar That returns 2040, while there is actually just 3 items in the test database. This is probably because there is a lot of html coming through as well. I am just looking for the number of entries in the database.

Comment: @omar The best solution is probably to pass a variable (preferably an array) from ajax.php to jQuery in the main page if that is possible.

Comment: then in your .php file, define number of entries and then retrieve them `var entries = html.entries` where entries is an object in the array.

Comment: I knew that @GeorgeStocker.. i thought this was too trivial a problem to post answers..thanks anyway :)

Comment: @hungerpain I'm not sure there's a "too trivial" close reason. However, the length of this conversation is pinging the moderator queue.

Comment: @omar I just realized that I can just access every element in that html object through jQuery. This is becoming quite the learning experience. Thanks, Omar.